# How does buying put orders on robinhood work if you purchase after hours

Tags: options, put-options

Here is my current scenario:

I bought a put option for `390.00` on `03/09` after market close, the status is still set as `queued`

I see now that the aftermarket price is `390.06`

If after market goes below my `put` price does that turn my `put` into a `call` and I lose money on it? or will the order just not be fulfilled

[image]

Comment: A serious question you need to ask yourself is what you actually try achieve here. You are putting orders for products into a system where you have not even a vague idea what they are supposed to be doing.

Comment: There's nothing invalid about buying puts with a strike price higher than the current market price. E.g. you can buy a 390 put when the SPY is 389. Nothing wrong with that. Such a put is called "in-the-money"

Comment: @user253751 of course not but you can't buy/sell options outside of market hours. OP is spending up to $2.32 per contract for options that expire today. SPY would need to drop to 386.68 just to break even (excluding fees...)

Comment: 40+ options on ETFs and ETNs (including SPY) trade after the stock market closes (until 4:15 PM),

Comment: @BobBaerker correct but now we're starting to split hairs... I said market hours not 4:00 PM. It's likely that the order was "queued" because it was placed outside of market hours (for that option.) Note that the screenshot shows 20:38 (8:38 PM). We don't know where OP is based but it's reasonable to assume that it's past 4:15 PM ET. In any case, OP states that he/she "bought a put option [...] after market close"

Answer (score 4):

Puts cannot turn into calls nor can calls turn into puts.

You bought a $390 SPY put for some undetermined cost.  If implied volatility increases and/or share price drops, your put will increase in value.

I would recommend that you read a book on options because based on your question, you don't have a good grasp of how options work.

Answer (score 2):

Careful what you're doing there... The order will likely be executed at the open.

If it goes through, you'll buy 7 puts, expiring tomorrow (same day). If SPY moves below 390 and you don't close out your position by 4:00 PM, your options will be exercised and you'll find yourself short 700 shares of SPY come Monday morning (unless you already have the shares...)

Depending on your account size/available margin, you might get margin called. If the market rallies, you could lose a good chunk of money and Robinhood might close your position for you, at whatever the market price is.

As Bob said, read up on options before proceeding...

Comment: SPY is an actual ETF with shares, right? I ask because there are also cash-settled options for this particular index.

Comment: @user253751 it's the world's oldest and most liquid ETF, it should go without saying...

Comment: @0xFEE1DEAD SPY is not the world's oldest such ETF. The oldest is a Canadian large cap index ETF that trades on the TSX since 1990. SPY is since 1993.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea are you sure about that? XIU's inception date is 9/28/1999. Either way, most investors have heard of SPY (I hope...)

Comment: @0xFEE1DEAD There was a merger and name change when the major Toronto Stock Exchange indexes were reorganized way back then. The original Toronto Index Participation Securities were established in 1990. https://www.newswire.ca/news-releases/toronto-stock-exchange-celebrates-30-years-of-etfs-880807286.html

Comment: Interesting, thanks for sharing. If we're being pedantic it wasn't actually an ETF back then... "Listed in 1990, the Toronto 35 Index® Participation Units, or TIPs®, was the world's first exchange-traded, index-linked product and served as the prototype for the modern-day ETF"

Comment: @0xFEE1DEAD It was an ETF back then, even if we're being pedantic. :) They just didn't have the name for the category yet. But, (a) it was a fund (not futures/derivatives), (b) it was exchange-traded, and most importantly, (c) it had a creation/redemption mechanism to keep the price and NAV close, setting it apart from closed-end funds.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea Alright, alright, alright... Canada wins! Happy?

Comment: @0xFEE1DEAD We'll settle it with a hockey game, USA v. CAN, next Olympics :D